# asyncio await results of future on another thread

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm trying to understand why the following isn't working in my complicated api to an execution broker, so I've made a generic simple example to try and work out whats going on.

I want to have a class (internal api) that can be instantiated, with an asyncio event loop running, which can then be called by other parts of the program to interact with an external api that has both long running subscriptions to updates on websockets and allows submitting orders, cancelling etc. I don't want the asyncio event loop to run and block the rest of the program which is why I'm trying to do it on a separate thread (welcome any feedback if there's a better way) and start the event loop up front rather than at the end like a script would to schedule multiple coroutines.

```
import asyncio
import random
import threading


class Api:
    def __init__(self):
        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self.start_loop()

    def start_loop(self):
        thr = threading.Thread(target=self.loop.run_forever, daemon=True)
        thr.start()

    async def get_data(self):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        return random.randint(1, 10)

    async def download_data(self):
        results = []
        for i in range(3):
            task = asyncio.ensure_future(self.get_data(), loop=self.loop)
            res = await task
            results.append(res)
        return results

    def download_all(self):
        result = self.download_data()
        return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = Api()
    results = a.download_all()
```

Results here is coroutine object, `<coroutine object Api.download_data at 0x7fdf5c3cc040>`

Is there a way to structure this as I want it, that download all calls the download_data which waits for each get_data call to finish before proceeding?

Expected for the results data to be a list of integers

Comment: randomly mixing sync and async methods and calling then from the main thread, and just telling a loop to start in another thread won't make anything work.
Other than that, just sorting these out, can make your overall design work - I will see if I can get you a working version of your example.

Answer (score 0):

The major problem there is that a co-routine can only be called by a running event-loop - so you can't simply say `download_data` is async and call it from a synchronous function, in another thread than the one running the loop.

The key is the `loop.call_soon_threadsafe` call in asyncio loops that will schedule a (synchronous) function to be called by a running asyncio loop in another thread. The target function can't itself await things in parallel, but can schedule things in the loop (create tasks and such).

```
import asyncio
import random
import threading
import time


class Api:
    def __init__(self):
        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self.start_loop()

    def start_loop(self):
        thr = threading.Thread(target=self.loop.run_forever, daemon=True)
        thr.start()

    async def get_data(self):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        return random.randint(1, 10)

    async def async_task(self, results):
        # This is an async co-routine that will
        # run in the loop-thread. just from here
        # we can call asynchronous things, and await their results!
        results.append(await self.get_data())

    def run_task(self, task, *args):
        # This is called by "call soon_thread_safe",
        # and is called by the asyncio loop in the
        # correct thread, but not as a co-routine.
        # so, we synchronously just create a new
        # task on the running loop and return:
        self.loop.create_task(task(*args))

    def download_data(self, n):
        results = []
        for i in range(n):
            self.loop.call_soon_threadsafe(self.run_task, self.async_task, results)
        return results

    def download_all(self):
        # The problem is you can't just call an async function
        # outside of an event loop, and without awaiting it.
        n = 5
        results = self.download_data(n)
        # wait for the completion of all async tasks in the other thread:
        while len(results) < n:
            time.sleep(0.1)
        return results
    
    def stop():
        self.loop.call_soon_threadsafe(self.loop.stop)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = Api()
    results = a.download_all()
    a.stop()
    print(results)
```

```
(env311) [gwidion@fedora tmp01]$ time python test_so.py 
[3, 9, 10, 1, 2]

real    0m1.191s
user    0m0.158s
sys     0m0.029s
```